# Binding a method to ViewCell Tapped

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to bind a method to viewcell tapped?

I have the following code:

```
<ViewCell Tapped="{Binding SwitchViews}">
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode' to type
'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode'.
```

Comment: You cannot bind to the Tapped-Property, since it is not a bindable Property. You could also subclass ViewCell, subscribe to the tapped event inside of the subclass and make it execute an ICommand that is set by a Bindable Property of return type ICommand

Comment: @Csharpest yep, after trying out different options thats exactly what I went with. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so Instead of giving the tapped event to viewcell give it to the child element of viewcell.

```
<Viewcell> 
       <Grid>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OpenCaseDetails" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            ...
            ...
       </Grid>
</Viewcell>
```

for more you can refer my blog post about interactive Listview at https://adityadeshpandeadi.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/the-more-interactive-listview/

feel free to drop by

Comment: Thats exactly what I did at the end, as you can see by my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a function called `SwitchViews` in your view mode (it may be a property but that's wrong).

> This is nearly always caused by assigning a value to an event in XAML, instead of specifying a method name.
>
> A common example is:

```
<Switch Toggled="{Binding IsToggled}" />
```

> Toggled is the name of an event. The property that was probably intended is called IsToggled.

(Taken from: https://oliverbrown.me.uk/2017/08/09/solved-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-xamarin-forms-xaml-elementnode-to-type-xamarin-forms-xaml-valuenode/)

Comment: This doesn't answer it. This works: Tapped="SwitchViews" but I dont want to use the method in the "behind code".

Comment: Can you post your ViewModel function ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it to work.

I created a Grid inside my ViewCell and added the following code:

```
  <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="List_ItemSelected" Command="{Binding SwitchViewsCommand}"/>
  </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

And in my ViewModel I did this:

```
 public ICommand SwitchViewsCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

This is in my constructor and executes the method I want.

```
SwitchViewsCommand = new Command(Tapped);
```